# Trying to understand Journey::Path::Pattern#spec (internal of Rails routing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, internals, journey

**Context:** I'm solving a problem where I need an external audit program to be able to understand and "apply" Rails routes. One option for writing this external program could been to parse the output of `rake routes`, but that would unnecessarily end-up duplicating the code which parses these routes and converts them into well-structured `Journey::Route` objects.

Therefore, my plan is to output `Rails.application.routes` to a common format (YAML, or JSON), which the external program can understand, and can build  a router based on this data.

**Question:** Given this context, I'm trying to understand the structure of the `Journey::Path::Paternet#spec` attribute, which occurs inside a `Journey::Route` object, and happens to be the center of all action.

For example, the following route - `/posts/:id` - gets converted to the following "spec" -

```
 #<Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x00007ff193327ee0
 @left=
  #<Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x00007ff193308630
   @left=
    #<Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x00007ff1933087e8
     @left=
      #<Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x00007ff193308bf8
       @left=#<Journey::Nodes::Slash:0x00007ff193308d38 @left="/", @memo=nil>,
       @memo=nil,
       @right=#<Journey::Nodes::Literal:0x00007ff193308c48 @left="posts", @memo=nil>>,
     @memo=nil,
     @right=#<Journey::Nodes::Slash:0x00007ff193308a40 @left="/", @memo=nil>>,
   @memo=nil,
   @right=#<Journey::Nodes::Symbol:0x00007ff1933086d0 @left=":id", @memo=nil, @regexp=/[^\.\/\?]+/>>,
 @memo=nil,
 @right=
  #<Journey::Nodes::Group:0x00007ff193309c10
   @left=
    #<Journey::Nodes::Cat:0x00007ff193308220
     @left=#<Journey::Nodes::Dot:0x00007ff1933084f0 @left=".", @memo=nil>,
     @memo=nil,
     @right=#<Journey::Nodes::Symbol:0x00007ff193308338 @left=":format", @memo=nil, @regexp=/[^\.\/\?]+/>>,
   @memo=nil>>
```

- What are the left/right attributes in a `Journey::Nodes::Cat` object? What decides which token will be "left" and which token will be "right"
- This looks suspiciously like a binary tree, but why is the very first token (i.e. the first `/`), the "innermost" (or a leaf node)? Shouldn't it be the "outermost" (or the root node)?
- What is an efficient way to walk down this data-structure while performing route matching?

Answer (score 2):

Journey is based on Finite State Machine that matches route, there's built-in visualizer (requires graphviz):

```
File.open('routes.html', 'wt'){|f| f.write Rails.application.routes.router.visualizer }
```

`Journey::Nodes::Cat` is only one of node types that you can encounter, it is binary node that matches `expressions` rule in path [grammar, see parser.y](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3bd534287139549cee10e10364344d66139d9237/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/parser.y#L7), left is first `expression`, `right` is all others, this produces loop that consumes all expressions.

Other thoughts about external routes analysis: Routes cannot be dumped into a static file in a generic case because they can contain:

- dynamic constraints with non-pure functions (for example - `get :r, constraints: ->{rand(2)>0}`, idea is that result can depend on something outside of request, time or state, etc.) When these are present - even rails router itself can produce different result on second run over the same request.
- mounted rack apps - can have hardcoded or non-rails routers
- rails engines - have rails router, so easier than generic rack apps, but trickery with mount points and merging into main app scope

But for simple case you can tap into rails' `ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector` which is used for `rake routes` and get structured routes info that is better that just parsing the latter output.

In gem `routes_coverage` I did this way:

```
class Inspector < ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector
  def collect_all_routes
    res = collect_routes(@routes)
    @engines.each do |engine_name, engine_routes|
      res += engine_routes.map{|er|
        er.merge({ engine_name: engine_name })
      }
    end
    res
  end

  def collect_routes(routes)
    routes.collect do |route|
      ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteWrapper.new(route)
    end.reject do |route|
      route.internal?
    end.collect do |route|
      collect_engine_routes(route)

      { name:   route.name,
        verb:   route.verb,
        path:   route.path,
        reqs:   route.reqs,
        original: route,
      }
    end
  end

res = Inspector.new(Rails.application.routes.routes.routes).collect_all_routes
```